# How to set command line argument using a variable in bash

Tags: bash, curl

I set a command line argument as below:

```
$TOKENARG='Authorization: Bearer 9042f9a3caacc63419be489aefec02a5eae338c33' 
curl -v -X DELETE -H $(echo $TOKENARG) http://localhost:3001/api/v1/articles/3
```

And desired result is:

```
curl -v -X DELETE -H 'Authorization: Bearer 9042f9a3caacc63419be489aefec02a5eae338c33' http://localhost:3001/api/v1/articles/3
```

But when I run the above one it doesn't work as expected and returns the following messages:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Bearer
>   * Rebuilt URL to: 9042f9a3caacc63419be489aefec02a5eae338c33
>    Could not resolve host: 9042f9a3caacc63419be489aefec02a5eae338c33

How should I pass argument using a variable?

Comment: please run your code thru shellcheck.net . Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't quote your command substitution, the string is split up into three words, `Authorization:`, `Bearer` and `9042f9a3caacc63419be489aefec02a5eae338c33`. To prevent that, you could quote it:

```
curl -v -X DELETE -H "$(echo $TOKENARG)" http://localhost:3001/api/v1/articles/3
```

But you don't need `echo` and the command substitution at all: `$(command)` has the same output as `command`, so you can use

```
curl -v -X DELETE -H "$TOKENARG" http://localhost:3001/api/v1/articles/3
```

Side note: all uppercase variable names should be used for environment variables only, see for example the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) (fourth paragraph), so better would be

```
$tokenarg='Authorization: Bearer 9042f9a3caacc63419be489aefec02a5eae338c33' 
curl -v -X DELETE -H "$tokenarg" http://localhost:3001/api/v1/articles/3
```